# How to use Guava with JBoss 6

Tags: java, guava, jboss6.x

I'm trying to use Guava for my project, and when starting JBoss there are many warnings:

```
WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Equals: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Equals has interface com.google.common.base.Equivalence as super class
WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:com.google.common.base.FunctionalEquivalence: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.common.base.FunctionalEquivalence has interface com.google.common.base.Equivalence as super class
WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultiset$1$1: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultiset$1$1 cannot access its superclass com.google.common.collect.Multisets$AbstractEntry
[...]
```

From my research, it seems there is an incompatibility with the old Google Collection.
This thread from [community.jboss.org](https://community.jboss.org/message/581507) propose to use **jboss-scanning.xml**. I have no change and JBoss documentation specifies that this file is used to filter the annotations...

Do you have already encountered this problem?

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, google collections and guava are incompatible, and it is stated quite clearly on the [google collections home page](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/):

> Guava is a fully compatible superset of the old Google Collections
>   Library. It also includes years worth of bug fixes, doc fixes, and
>   performance fixes, so we strongly encourage you to use Guava instead
>   of Google Collections.
>
> If your application ever ends up with both google-collect-1.0.jar and
>   guava-r##.jar on the same classpath, simply remove the Google
>   Collections JAR and you should be fine. **If you don't remove it, it
>   will either cause terrible problems (if it comes before guava in the
>   classpath) or will never even be seen anyway (if it comes after)**.

So basically: either remove google collections from the classpath or see to it that guava is loaded first.